# making a:hover shrink the img

Tags: css, button, hover

My button links are just  links in the html with a background image in css. In the CSS I also have the dimensions of the image so that the whole thing is displayed.

I want the image to shrink to 95% whenever the mouse hovers over the image. I have the a:hover css but changing the dimensions to 95% there doesn't do it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

You can see the sample page at http://granthoneymoon.com/temp.html and the nav buttons are at the top inside the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
a { transition: transform 0.5s; }
a:hover { transform: scale(0.95); }
```

You can change `0.5` to whatever timing suits you best.
Also you would need to add specific `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-o-` prefix for older browser versions.

Comment: What does the transform 0.5s do?

Comment: I put it in just like you have it and I see no change. :-/

Comment: 0.5s is the amount of time it will perform the transform, meaning in this current case "half second". 1.0s for example is 1 second.

Comment: I like the look of what you have going there, but what if you have a background img in the link class?